# Database for storing PDF files

Tags: mysql, excel, pdf

I am new to programming and I need some help trying to understand how this works.

So I got assigned to create a database or a storage that will have mostly PDF documents in it. We keep those documents on our company network server, so I need to make a database that will automatically store those documents based on their type, I need to assign them all with a code when storing them, a code that will have the prefix INC, numbering, year and category letter in it. Then when we need to pull them out and find them based on that information the code should change the prefix INC to prefix OUT.

I tried googling and asking AI in detail about this, I also created some codes with Python and a database in MySql Workbench but I am still not sure how this should look and work.

Also my boss said that this was possible to do with Excel, does anyone have any tips?

I wrote the whole code in MySQL Workbench with the help of the AI but I am not sure if it's practical and how to pull the pdf files automatically from our server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In industry we are using cloud services for that document. and save only document name (in our database) for retrieving it from cloud services. saving document on cloud services is a best practice.

for example if we have a file of 20MB named file1.xlsx
in that case we save fileName in our database file1.xlsx
and save file on cloud services.

Please Learn about services like aws, azure

Answer (score 1):

Hi IF YOU ARE using sql for a samll project basicall we dont store the whole pdf on the database we store the pdf inside a folder (pdfinstall..any name u wnat) then storing the path of the pdf inside the db